# Rails SMTPAuthenticationError Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, actionmailer

I've developed a Rails 3 app and I've recently added an action mailer for when a user signs up.
Testing it locally and it sends an email perfectly, but when I move it to the server at test it for a new user signing up, I get the following error.


I am running Nginx on the server with the original configurations, both local machine and server are running ubuntu 11.10

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in UsersController#create
535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted.
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:26:in 'create'


In users_controller.rb - create - Line 26 is `UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver`

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to University Sports!"
      redirect_to @user
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

In development.rb I have the following code:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'www.mydomain.co.uk',
    :user_name            => 'email@mydomain.co.uk',
    :password             => 'email_password',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "univeristy.sports@louisgriffiths.co.uk"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://www.mydomain:3000"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to University Sports")
  end
end
```

Comment: is your server set to run in production mode? if so you need to add the settings you did in development.rb to production.rb

Comment: I have tried that as well, but I haven't had any luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and found that my application.yml file was overriding it so I deleted that and now it works fine!